# Unity visual scripting not changing sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bolt

For some reason, the API only support visual scripting which is hell for me. But some of the function work and some don't, not sure if it's bug please help.
[image]

This is driving me crazy because I try to change the sprite to something else, and you can see the link between the get item and set sprite, the sprite that passes out is correct however the image is not changing. Then I try to change the colour, it did change the colour but not the image. This is driving me crazy, I tried this for hours but there is not many visual scripting example on the internet.

Comment: `For some reason, the API only support visual scripting` .. the API of what exactly?

Comment: The api is Spatial VR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just found out is the animator disturbed the process. the animator keeps running overriding the function(due to the animator changing the sprite with event key, but the function itself is fine. when I turn the animator off, then it works fine.

Comment: Does this mean you've solved the problem or should it be additional information in the question and not an answer?

Comment: Solved it, the animator keeps running overriding the function, but the function itself is fine. when I turn the animator off, then it works fine.